# How to add multiple "submit" buttons in Webform

Tags: webforms

If I add a button to a webform creating a module with something like this in it:

```
$form['actions']['submit_2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit 2'),
);
```

It appears in my webform, but it doesn't submit the webform.

If I add a custom handler for this button like this:

```
$form['actions']['submit_start'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Début du Changement'),
  '#submit' => array(custom_handler),
);
```

When I click it, the custom_handler is called but the webform is not submitted.

How can I add multiple buttons that all submits the webform, but some add this submission other functions (like a specific "drupal_set_message")?

Comment: Maybe take a step back to the actual problem you want to solve: "How can I add a custom submit message?" and ask your question that way.

Comment: Webform for Drupal 8 .support adding multiple submit buttons/actions via the UI.  You can duplicate the existing submit buttons

Comment: Ok, Thanks ! Except (i should have said this before, but I am in drupal 7) @leymannx I know how to add a custom submit message. What I want is multiple submit buttons with different messages! I can add a button, but don't know how to make this new one able to submit the form...

Comment: The real question is just like @leymannx said what do you want to accomplish?, if you want to see different messages based on the submit, then write a handler that does this functionality, Instead of duplicating the submit extend the current submit with different handlers based on a specific state.

Comment: What I want to accomplish, exactly is, when editing a submission, add a button "Start" that Save the changes and add some information in a field of the webform (the time in a "start" field for exemple) and a "Stop" button, that do exactly the same but in the "stop" field. And, of course, keep  the "Save" Button ... And writting this, I do realize that ther is nothing to do with the "submit" button, as it is a "Save" button... And don't want this when submitting the form in fact...